# Objective-C: Boxing VS Literal

Tags: objective-c, object, boxing

Which construct should I use, why? I'll make an example with `NSArray`. The same apply to other "boxed" objects, such as `NSDictionary`, `NSNumber`...

```
NSArray *arr1 = @[object1, object2, object3];
```

or

```
NSArray *arr2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:object1, object2, object3, nil];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two constructs produce identical effect for `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` objects. The difference is that the first syntax is not available prior to the 2012 version of the compiler, while `arrayWithObjects:` works with all versions of the language.

If you are not planning for your code to compile with older versions of the complier, the new syntax is gives you better readability, especially for `NSNumber` objects. Compare

```
NSArray *arr = @[@1, @2, @3];
```

vs.

```
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
    [NSNumber numberWithInteger:1]
,   [NSNumber numberWithInteger:2]
,   [NSNumber numberWithInteger:3]
,   nil
];
```

Comment: So, technically, they're the same? From which iOS version is the new syntax available?

Comment: @Eddie It's not tied to iOS version, the version of the compiler changed independently of iOS version. The changeover happened in early 2012. Here is the [documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html).

Comment: So, I shouldn't care about the compiler and just use the simple syntax, since I only use the lastest compiler, is that right?

Answer (score 1):

Neither `NSArray` nor `NSDictionary` literals are "boxed". Boxing refers to when you make objects out of scalars or non-object types. Cocoa arrays and dictionaries are always objects.

Boxing *is* the relevant terminology for `NSNumber`, though. For example, `1` is an `int`, a scalar type (not an object). `@1` is an `NSNumber`, the result of boxing `1`. However, technically, I'd say that `[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]` is also boxing. It's just that `@1` is a more convenient syntax.

There is a difference between:

```
NSArray *arr1 = @[object1, object2, object3];
```

and

```
NSArray *arr2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:object1, object2, object3, nil];
```

In the first, if any of `object1`, `object2`, or `object3` hold `nil`, you will get a runtime exception. In the second, any `nil` just terminates the argument list. So, if `object2` is `nil`, `arr2` will end up as a single-element array holding only `object1`. `NSArray` will never even get around to considering `object3` because, as far as it's concerned, the argument list was terminated after the first element.

Rarely, you can make legitimate use of this behavior (in which case, I'd clearly make note of it in the comments), but most often this is unexpected and undesirable behavior. It's a particularly pernicious sort of bug.